# Would it be correct to say "thank you to everyone"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, agreement

Would it be correct to say "Thank you to everyone"? It seems like there would be two direct objects to the verb "thank".

Comment: Sounds OK to me. If you google the phrase, there's 119 million hits, so lots of other folk have used it.

Comment: Surely *everyone* there is an indirect object? What makes you think it's a direct object? Perhaps *thank* can be a [ditransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb): what makes you think it has two direct objects here?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think what he's finding confusing is that it's thanking both "you" and "everyone" at the same time. But it's not really a problem because "thank you" is being used as an idiom that just means "thanks".